# Running Spring Batch jobs from the command line

Tags: spring, maven, maven-plugin, spring-batch

I don't know how to call a Job defined in Spring Batch using `CommandLineJobRunner`, documentation details are not enough for me.

I've followed the [Spring Batch official guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/) to write Jobs in Spring Batch using Java annotations e.g. `@EnableBatchProcessing` because I wanted to avoid XML configuration files for the description of the job, the steps, etc.

So far I have:

- a configuration class (`com.package.bla.bla.ClassContainingTheBatchConfiguration` see below) where I've put all the stuff defining `ItemReader`, `ItemProcessor`, `ItemWriter`, `Job`, and `Step` (with `return jobs.get("nameOfTheJob")` see below) using a `@Bean` annotaion.
- a class with a `main` method with `SpringApplication.run(...)` and and annotation with `@ImportResource("classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml")` to import some beans I need when processing the data in the Job.

On the Maven side I am currently using some plugins:

- `maven-jar-plugin` specifying `<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>` and the class containing the main method in the tag `<mainClass>`
- `maven-assembly-plugin` because I would like a unique executable `jar` containing all the stuff in the dependencies, I am using `<phase>package</package>` to be able to build the jar in the `package` phase, I am also using `<goal>single</goal>` to be able to properly build the jar using the `assembly`
- `maven-compiler-plugin` specifying I am using Java 1.7

I think I've configured all the things I need to configure, however after having a Maven `BUILD SUCCESS` I am not able to run the job from the command line:

```
java -cp ./target/JAR_FILE_NAME.jar org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner com.package.bla.bla.ClassContainingTheBatchConfiguration nameOfTheJob
```

Is throwing `IOException` due to the `java.io.FileNotFoundException` regarding `com.package.bla.bla.ClassContainingTheBatchConfiguration`. How should I specify the parameters in the command line in order to get the Job executed?

Comment: Documentation 'details' are ridiculous. I can hardly imagine running an existing job based on documentation only. I just wonder what was the learning curve to a guy who created the job...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already using `SpringApplication` from Spring Boot, why not finish the job and use `@EnableAutoConfiguration` as well, and also the Maven plugin (see for example [this guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/))? That way you will get something working pretty quickly and you can always add your own features later.

Comment: Oh I forgot mentioning that the class containing the `main` method is annotated with `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. I actually would like to have some sort of control over the jobs I can run i.e. chose which job should be run by the `SpringApplication.run(...)`. That's why I thought maybe I could use somehow `CommandLineJobRunner` providing an annotated class rather than a XML configuration file.

Comment: With `@EnableAutoConfiguration` you can set "spring.batch.jobName" (up to RC3) or "spring.batch.jobNames" (since yesterday) to list the jobs to execute (see here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/docs/howto.md#execute-spring-batch-jobs-on-startup). You can do that in your main method if you prefer but it's probably better to pass it on the command line (a bit like you were trying to do with the CLJR).

Comment: That sounds like great news! Well how should I specify this `spring.batch.jobName` parameter? I thought I could have set something near `@EnableAutoConfiguration` (which is calling `BatchAutoConfiguration`) but that's not the case. I've set the Spring Boot parent version in Maven to be `1.0.0.RC3`. (I am quite new to Spring and stuck with the documentation and the source code browsing)

Comment: If you're not very familiar with Spring  why not try to work through some of [the guides](http://spring.io/guides/)? Externalizing configuration in a Boot application is covered in various places, including [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot#externalized-configuration).

Comment: Ok, I've done some tests but I am still not able to pass some parameters from the command line either they are directly property names and values or paths to a properties file. `$ java -jar target/jarName.jar spring.batch.job.names=nonExistingJobName` make me see in the log `2014-02-28 16:32:58.977 [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner - Running default command line with: [spring.batch.job.names=nonExistingJobName]`

Comment: To add properties to the environment using the command line you need to add "--" to the argument (I'll make that more obvious in the docs). You porobably want `jobNames` not `job.names` as well (but it might work with the period if you're lucky).

Comment: I've tried both `job.names` and `jobNames` from the command line with a `--` prefix (e.g. `$ java -jar target/jarName.jar --spring.batch.job.names=nonExistingJobName`) and I am still getting an unwanted job executed, e.g. after seeing the previously mentioned log statement, I am also seeing: `2014-02-28 17:13:15.866 [main] INFO  org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [FlowJob: [name=existingJobName]] launched with the following parameters: [{-spring.batch.job.names=nonExistingJobName}]
` Should I set something in the `main` method related to `SpringApplication`?

Comment: You can see the parameters being passed to the job from the command line. To me it looks suspicious that you have "-" in front of the `spring.batch.job.names` (which should be `jobNames`). Is "nonExistingJobName" an actual job name in your context? I'm a bit confused about that. If you can publish your code somewhere I'll have a look.

Comment: Well I do not own the rights on this code, I can not publish it. Thanks for all the details you provided so far, they have been really helpful.

Comment: What maven dependency is needed for `@EnableBatchProcessing` ? I tried with `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>` but it doesn't contain that annotation.

Comment: I think it does. Look again. Check your spelling or something.

Answer (score 1):

If the first argument to the `CommandLineJobRunner` is your `@Configuration` FQCN instead of a resource path, the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` constructor that's called from the `CommandLineJobRunner`'s `start()` method will break.

```
int start(String jobPath, String jobIdentifier, String[] parameters, Set<String> opts) {

    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = null;

    try {
        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(jobPath);
```

If you've already written a class with a `main()`, that replaces the `CLJR`, you shouldn't be passing `CLJR` as the class name in the command line. Pass that instead.

Comment: Yeah I suspected that, I was not sure. Well, in the class containing the `main` method I would like to explicitly specify which job should be run. I can not find a way using a `main` method with `SpringApplication.run(...)` though.

Comment: `java -jar ... --spring.batch.jobNames=myJobName` didn't work?

Comment: @DaveSyer : This command looks good. How do I pass job parameters and how do I infer the same in the job config bean ?

Answer (score 0):

dont use spring.batch.job.enabled=false
then run using java -jar [jar-files] --spring.batch.job.names=[job-name]

Comment: Hi AndreLucky - please will you add a little more detail to your answer? I would love to know HOW and WHY this works?